# Jquery - blur and keyup triggers multiple times

Tags: jquery, blur, keyup

I've got this code which enables an input, focuses on it and then triggers an ajax request when you click out or press enter.

```
$("body").on('click', '.input', function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#inp" + id).prop('disabled', false).focus();

        $("#imp" + id).on('blur keyup',function(e) {  
            if (e.type === 'blur' || e.keyCode === 13) {

                    $.ajax({ url : 'file.php?var=' + var + '&nextvar=' + nextvar, 
                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log (response);

                        } 
                    })
                $("#imp" + id).prop('disabled', true);
            }
        });  

    })
```

It seems to work fine, apart from pressing enter causes it to trigger the ajax multiple times.

Can anyone advise why ?

Thanks

Comment: Your event handler is bound to both the blur and keyup event. So if both events trigger then your handler is called twice. Enter is probably causing a form submit which causes the input element to lose focus anyway. I think you can just remove the keyup event if you only need it for enter. Ow and you bind the events when you `click` on the input. Which means if you click it twice your handler is called twice too for each event.

Comment: Just after my if statement for blur/keyCode I've added `if (e.keyCode === 13) $(this).off("blur");`  That seems to resolve it

Answer (score 2):

Just add a simple check if its done or not. Then refresh it whenever you are prepeared to do another click check

```
var done = false;

function ajaxCall() {
    if(!done) {
        $.ajax({ url : 'file.php?var=' + var + '&nextvar=' + nextvar, 
            success: function(response) {
                console.log (response);
                done = true;
            } 
        });
    }
    $("#imp" + id).prop('disabled', true);
}

$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("body").on('click', '.input', function(){
        id = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#inp" + id).prop('disabled', false).focus(); 
  });

    $("#imp" + id).on('blur',function(e) {  ajaxCall() });
    $("#imp" + id).on('keyup',function(e) {  if(e.keyCode === 13) ajaxCall() });
});
```

this runs only once (note `done = false`) if you want to reset it, make the global "done" var false again.

Comment: Thanks, this helps but I still get the duplication of the ajax request,

Comment: To be honest you dont need your blur, keyup events onclick inputs. that would solve alot of problems. Let me edit the code  abit.

Comment: I edited the code a bit. see if it works. It shouldnt summon it two times now. Since I suspect body click was doing same thing. Your input is disabled anyways, and keyup, blur code doesnt work on disabled. I would add function this case aswell